# Can someone explain what the function "sub" is doing to the above character vector?

Tags: r

I am new to programming and started with R since I need it in my Master's courses can someone help me understand the solution step by step.

```
awards <- c("Won 1 Oscar.",
  "Won 1 Oscar. Another 9 wins & 24 nominations.",
  "1 win and 2 nominations.",
  "2 wins & 3 nominations.",
  "Nominated for 2 Golden Globes. 1 more win & 2 nominations.",
  "4 wins & 1 nomination.")

sub(".*\\s([0-9]+)\\snomination.*$", "\\1", awards)
```

Solution:
A vector of character strings containing:

```
Won 1 Oscar., 24, 2, 3, 2, 1
```

Comment: Please remove the C++ tag.

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html and https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html

Answer (score 2):

The function call `sub(".*\\s([0-9]+)\\snomination.*$", "\\1", awards)` does the following:

In the entries of character vector `awards` it looks for a pattern of the form

- some characters (optional) (`.*`)
- followed by a space (`\\s`)
- followed by a number (`[0-9]+`)
- followed by a space (`\\s`)
- followed by the word 'nomination' (`nomination`)
- followed by some characters (optional) (`.*`)
- followed by the end of the string (`$`)

If it can find such a pattern, then it replaces the entry with the number it found, if not, then it leaves the entry as it is.

Hence `"Won 1 Oscar."` stays as it is and `"Won 1 Oscar. Another 9 wins & 24 nominations."` is replaced by the number `24`.

Comment: Is the parenthesis around [0-9]+ i.e "([0-9]+)" against "[0-9]+" make a difference? is it necessary for the parenthesis to be present so that the argument "\\1" takes the matched digits to replace the vector instead of the user specifying the replacement vector?

Comment: Exacly. The parentheses around `[0-9]` turn the pattern into a capturing group. The parentheses capture the text matched by the pattern inside it. This text can then be referenced using `\\1` for the first group, `\\2` for the second group (if there are more than one in your regular expression) etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
[1]"Won 1 Oscar"
```

no pattern match

```
[2]"24"
```

matched whole vector element and 24 was identified by `([0-9]+)` as group. `"\\1"` captures first group so the vector element is replaced by this group.

The remaining elements analogously